# What should i do to resolve this issue on Git?

Tags: windows, git, git-bash

I am new to Unix commands and would like to have some help regarding it.

I am want to practice commands on my Windows Machine. I have installed GitBash and I am trying to execute commands on it. But every time I press enter I get this issue:

```
$ git init
C:/Users/.git: Permission denied

lenovo@LAPTOP-7Q4QK8A7 MINGW64 /c/Users
$ git clone https://github.com/06-glitch/Rainbow/commit/32c6e7cc3c37d20ff368a2095c34522da297b174
fatal: could not create work tree dir '32c6e7cc3c37d20ff368a2095c34522da297b174': Permission denied
```

Could anyone please help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

Problem:Your are trying to clone in the users folder which is not accessible.

Answer:Change your directory to the Desktop or any other folder and use the git commands

cd means "change directory"

Use the below code to change directory to root:

```
cd ~
```

or In my case my desktop name Aakarsh Teja so.. try cd to that name Remember you have to use quotes if your folder name consists of a SPACE.

```
cd "Aakarsh Teja"/Desktop
```

Now you can use your commands for git.

Make sure your git bash is in your destination folder.

```
Aakarsh Teja@MINGW64 ~/Desktop
$git clone <gitlink>
```